# Is possible multi-threading read form file stored on magnetic hard-drive

Tags: python, multithreading

I must increase performance of processing some big file (up 4GB), and i figure that, i can exercise 48 hardware thread to process this file. But on the working server, there also magnetic hard drive. 
I'm not allowed to load this file to RAM.
And my question is that, did this multi-threading read from file is possible? Did thread must wait on another thread to end read specific line from file, so that on the hardware level this will be sequential processing, but on the code level, processing will be multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you may not load the file into ram - you mean the whole file at once? to read it from the disk you are still reading it into memory, you just not might be keeping it in memory long.

The fastest way to read the file will remain a sequential read of the file, and not to have multiple threads moving the disk head around. If you can detach the processing of the data from the reading of the data, you could have a single thread reading the data sequentially passing off chunks of the reads to other threads performing the processing.

No language has been tagged on the question, so a more precise technique to use is difficult for anyone to answer. For example - in go, I would have 1 worker reading the file sequentially, placing the lines read onto a channel, and create as many worker routines as was necessary to process the channel.

Comment: language specified by my leader is Python. You proposal that, load chunk of file to RAM, and process this chunk by many threads?

Comment: The term 'process the data' is not very well defined here, since we do not know what you are doing to it, but I would propose you make the sequential reader independent of the multi-threaded processing, to keep the fastest possible read speed, while also allowing data to be processed in parallel - it relies on the premise though that you do not have to worry too much about the order of the rows in the file, otherwise more logic to understand the ordering is also then required.

Comment: Ok, i explain You more about this file... Lines on this file is splited into two categories Time, and Msg. Process msg line require konwledge about last time line. So at first i must split file in approximately 48 chunk, and on begin this chunk, find time line, if no, chunk must be extended. This is first step to process this file. If i had splited chunk (with different length) then i allowed to start process this file (decode msg, paste timestamp, and paste to other database) by other threads.

Comment: The complexity to sufficient that you should include this in your question, and detail how you plan to divide the work into parallel streams (regardless of the file read)

Comment: I take it, that amount and distribution msg and time line is regular (on one time line, accrue 4 msg line), so split this file on 48 no-regular chunk will be no high-priced

Comment: Chunk is just range of lines in file. Begin of chunk must be time line, becouse, without knowledge about timestamp, i unable to to process msg item. If begin of chunk is msg line, i must move pointer to next/previous line to find time line. So change range one chunk, i change also range of previous chunk, becouse file length is const.

Comment: That sounds like your reader can chunk up the data then and pass onto a queue / channel for the multi-threaded readers to process chunks as they become available.

Comment: First step is split file into chunks: get specific lines positions, and move this information to threads. Thread use correct chunk range. But if multithreading read from file is not possible, this solution has no sense.

Comment: In optimal case, first split file into chunks, set pointers precisly into time line, so i musn't change ranges this chunks